# Calling functions from within linq statement

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Just wondering if this is the most efficient method of doing this? is there a way of having all the linq within one statement instead of calling a method, like a subselect or something?

```
newEmployee = (from emp
               in db.employees
               select new 
               {
                   a.EmployeeID,
                   a.Username,
                   Status = emp.GetEmployeeCurrentStatus(a.Username)
               }).ToList();
```

This is the  GetEmployeeCurrentStatus which returns the status of the employee:

```
 public string GetEmployeeCurrentStatus(string username)
        {
            using (Entities db = new Entities())
            {
                var times = (from d in db.TimeTables
                             where d.DateTime == DateTime.Today &&
                             d.Employee.Username == username
                             select d)
                             .OrderByDescending(d => d.TimeID).FirstOrDefault();

                return (x.ClockOut == null ? "IN" : "OUT");                                
            }
        }
```

Comment: user - i can't see how that method is working. where does x.clockout come from?? should it be times.clockout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about:

```
newEmployee = (db.employees.Select(emp => new
                  {
                      emp.EmployeeID,
                      emp.Username,
                      Status = db.TimeTables
                        .Where(d => d.Employee.Username == emp.Username
                          && d.DateTime == DateTime.Today)
                          .Select(x => x.ClockOut == null ? "IN" : "OUT")
                          .FirstOrDefault()
                  })).ToList();
```

Your attempt may *appear* cleaner and is functionally ok. However, it is firing up a secondary db call. This will be bad for scalability and performance. The version i've posted uses the same initial db connection and will make the join 1-1. This will result in tighter, faster queries as well as lower resource usage.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot really call a custom method inside a query (or a part of a query that will be executed using the databse). You have essentially two options:

- Call `ToList` before performing the `select` that needs to call the method (this way, the method will be called on in-memory data)
- Compose the query such that it can all run on the SQL server if it is possible. This can be done using `AsExpandable` extension in [predicate builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx). For more information on how this works, see also [my blog post](http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-linq-queries.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

its fine for small data (employees count) but since each `GetEmployeeCurrentStatus` requires an sql new connection so its not that best practice.
I personally will get all employees (one trip to database) and then get all employees status (one trip to database) so i cashed them all, now i'll join them locally

Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of efficiency, having GetEmployeeCurrentStatus(...) as a method makes the code clearer and more reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using LINQ to SQL or EF, I would refactor your query to use a `Join`. That way, you will execute a single efficient SQL query on the database, instead of two separate queries.